# Generate multiple new DataFrames based on the datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a single DataFrame in the following format:

```
Date        Hour        Information
                               
2020-11-28  11:14:28           10.0
2020-11-28  11:14:30           15.4
2020-11-28  11:14:33            6.9
2020-11-28  11:14:35           27.0
2020-11-28  11:14:37           70.0
2020-11-28  11:14:40           37.1
2020-11-28  11:14:42            2.4
2020-11-28  11:15:20           11.9
2020-11-28  11:15:22           14.0
2020-11-28  11:15:24          122.8
2020-11-28  11:15:27          10.12
2020-11-28  11:15:29          56.86
2020-11-28  11:15:31          00.54
2020-11-28  11:15:34          01.87
2020-11-28  11:15:36            1.0
2020-11-28  11:24:21          45.45
2020-11-28  11:24:23            9.0
2020-11-28  11:24:26           90.5
2020-11-28  11:24:28            0.0
2020-11-28  11:24:30           5.34
.           .                     .
.           .                     .
.           .                     .
2020-11-30  10:34:12           10.0
2020-11-30  10:34:14           15.4
```

I need to be able to organize the information on the right column generating a new DataFrame containing the Information and the Hour for each datetime in the left column, so that i have like the following:

```
DataFrame1:
Datetime    Hour        Information
2020-11-28  11:14:28           10.0
2020-11-28  11:14:30           15.4
.           .                     .
.           .                     .
.           .                     .
2020-11-28  23:59:00           4.42

DataFrame2:
Datetime    Hour        Information
2020-11-29  00:00:00           18.7
.           .                     .
.           .                     .
.           .                     .
2020-11-28  23:59:00           7.54
```

And so on with all the other days I have, which not necessarily start in January 1st, but always has records for consecutive days.
I've tried to use .groupby() but couldn't find a way to use it wihout getting the mean, sum, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those multiple Dataframes that you want can be stored in tuple you could do the following

```
def format_df(df, date_time):
  df["DateTime"] = date_time
  return df.reset_index(drop=True)

dfs_array = tuple(format_df(grouped_df, date_time) for date_time, grouped_df in original_df.groupby("Date"))
```